# Kotlin TestCoroutineDispatcher hangs on cancelAndJoin() after yield()

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlintest

I have code that is essentially the following:

```
var job: Job? = null

fun startJob() = runBlocking(dispatcher) {
    job = CoroutineScope(dispatcher).launch { myJob() }
}

suspend fun myJob() {
    // work block 1
    ...
    yield()

    // work block 2
    ...
    yield()

    // work block 3
    ...
    yield()
    ...
}

fun cancelJob() = runBlocking(dispatcher) {
    job?.cancelAndJoin()
}

fun main() {
    startJob()
    cancelJob()
}
```

When I run the above with dispatcher = Dispatchers.IO or Dispatchers.Default, it works fine. However, setting dispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatchers simply hangs at the cancelAndJoin().

I'm suspecting it's related to TestCoroutineDispatcher's behavior in handling yield(). According to [this](https://medium.com/@ralf.stuckert/testing-coroutines-introduction-4ab6733c7599), yield() will only resume if runCurrent() is called. But given the structure of my code, I'm not sure where to call runCurrent(), or if it's even the right approach.